# Removing permanent marker marks from phone screen

Tags: cleaning, phone

What would be the best way to remove marks from my smartphone's screen, which have been caused accidentally from a permanent marker ? Note that my phone unfortunately isn't waterproof.

Also, I have tried wiping with a slightly wet cloth, and also using those liquids that are used for window cleaning. No effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubbing alcohol should work fine. I did a little research for some other solutions, and I found an article dedicated to removing permanent marker here:

http://www.onegoodthingbyjillee.com/2015/07/how-to-remover-permanent-marker-from-just-about-anything.html

Good luck!

Comment: That's a very helpful link, thank you. If alcohol works, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Excellent. Keep me posted!

Answer (score 3):

One option we used a lot on whiteboards being written on with permanent markers, was to overwrite the previous markings with the whiteboard markers. This dissolves the permanent marker, and leaves the whiteboard markings which are easily wiped away with a cloth.

I don't see why the same trick should not work for a smartphone screen, as well.

Comment: Ya. I also have observed the same thing!!